# How to mock a function called as default argument

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I have a class containing a timestamp. In the init function the initial timestamp is set to the argument provided, with a default value of 'time.monotonic()'. I also have and update function that sets the timestamp, also using time.monotonic()

When unit-testing this class I want to mock out time.monotonic, to get a predictable result.

However, the call in the default argument is always to the real time.monotonic

ClassWithTimestamp.py:

```
import time

class ClassWithTimestamp:
    def __init__(self, value={}, timestamp=time.monotonic()):
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def update(self):
        self.timestamp = time.monotonic()
```

ClassWithTimestampTest.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import ClassWithTimestamp

class ClassWithTimestampTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ClassWithTimestamp.time.monotonic = mock.Mock(name='now')
        ClassWithTimestamp.time.monotonic.return_value = 1000

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_init(self):
        sut = ClassWithTimestamp.ClassWithTimestamp()
        self.assertEqual(sut.timestamp, 1000)

    def test_update(self):
        sut = ClassWithTimestamp.ClassWithTimestamp()
        sut.update()
        self.assertEqual(sut.timestamp, 1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When run:

```
python3 ClassWithTimestampTest.py -v
test_init (__main__.ClassWithTimestampTest) ... FAIL
test_update (__main__.ClassWithTimestampTest) ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: test_init (__main__.ClassWithTimestampTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClassWithTimestampTest.py", line 16, in test_init
    self.assertEqual(sut.timestamp, 1000)
AssertionError: 762811.874163785 != 1000

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

It explains my problem, the default argument is called at the time of defining the init function, not executing it.

So my code was buggy to begin with as I intended the timestamp to be set to the construction time.

My revised code is

```
def __init__(self, value={}, timestamp=None):
    if timestamp:
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    else:
        self.timestamp = time.monotonic()
```

The problem itself still stands, the only way I see is to overwrite the member of the class after construction with the output of the mocked function.